# DateTimePicker value not updated onLeave when typing a single digit number

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datetimepicker

There has been a problem I have always struggled with. I have an application in which I relay on `DateTimePicker` values for lots of calculations. The dates are usually typed in this controls, and users type single digit days or months without the leading zeros (i.e. 9/9/17  or 10/6/17) and the controls completes the date.

However, when this happens in `Validating`, `Validated`, `Leave`, `ValueChanged`, etc events, the `DateTimePicker.Value` reflects the preview value, before updating.

For example, the control sets the date to `DateTime.Today` (06/09/2017) and the user types the value to previews month without the leading zeros (5/09/2017). In this case, in the previewsly mentioned events, the `DateTimePicker.Value` will still be 06/09/2017, even though it has changed. It is important to clarify that if the user types the date with leading zeros (05/09/2017), the value is correctly updated in the event.

The value is updated correctly, and if I validate the value after this events (i.e. when the user clics a button), I can see the updated value. But this is not what is required.

In the following example, another control which depends on the correct value is wrongly updated.

```
private void nochesFormattedTextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   fechaFinDateTimePicker.Value = fechaDateTimePicker.Value.AddDays(nochesFormattedTextBox.Text != "" ? int.Parse(nochesFormattedTextBox.Text) : 0);
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's completely normal: those events are fired BEFORE the real value is updated in the control. I recomand that you use Change event or, event better: Validated. Validated is fired after the Validating event, and your always sure that you data is valid. You don't need to implement validating by the way... Validated is ALWAYS fired. The problem with Change is the value could be wrong, cause the data could not be valid. Then I thing you should use Validated.

Comment: It actually also happens with the `Validated` event also. However, the solution was using the `ValueChanged` event. Thanks!